# how to split sentence and get specific nsstring

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I want one sentence in `NSString` object like this:

```
NSString *myWords = @"Hi,I'm Janatan! I love objective C!!!";
```

I want split this sentence to more part for example :

**first part : Hi**

**second part : I'm Janatan**

**third part : I love objective C**

I want do this with loop but I don't know how to do it. I want split words until arrive to signs (! , ? . and etc)

please guide me about that.

Comment: `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:`? Or replacing "special" characters with "characters+\n"?

Comment: If want to do in swift please check the below link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet, e.g.:

```
NSString *myWords = @"Hi,I'm Janatan! I love objective C!!!";
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
          [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"!,"]];
```