# Swift - Get information from String to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift, nsmutablearray

This is my string:

```
(
    "2|Apples / amount",
    "5|Pizza / pieces",
    "10|Oranges / amount",
    "1|Brownie / piece"
)
```

How to get the number, name of the food and unit of the food in arrays

```
var number:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var foodName:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var foodUnit:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
```

Comment: That's not a string, it's an array with 4 strings in it.

Comment: it was array but I inserted in string now I want to make an arrays from this string, the code is the println of the string

Comment: Your question is not clear. You say you have a string, but what you show is an array. Log your string and post the exact log results so we can see what your string actually looks like.

Comment: this is the exact log result of the string via println() I got it from Core Data in String before I added it in Core Data it was in array but when you add array in Core Data it turns into a String

Answer (score 1):

You will need to [Split a string into an array.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array%20split%20a%20array%20into%20a%20string)

Not tested but this is the gist of it:

```
    let myFood = ["2|Apples / amount", "5|Pizza / pieces", "10|Oranges / amount", "1|Brownie / piece"]

foreach value in myFood {

let numberAndInfo = myFood.componentsSeparatedByString("|")
// Insert numberAndInfo[0] in your number array.
let foodAndAmount = numberAndInfo[1].componentsSeparatedByString(" / ")
// Insert foodAndAmount[0] into foodName
// Insert foodAndAmount[1] into foodUnit

}
```

EDIT: Apologize for the indentation.

Comment: yes but I don't have an array, the code with food amount and units is string, I know how to do it with array but it's not an array...

Comment: I don't think I get it. So you only have one string like this?: "2|Apples / amount5|Pizza / pieces10|Oranges / amount1|Brownie / piece" - Your initial code does show an array of strings.

Comment: I had an array but in Core Data you have to added in to String and now when I get it from Core Data is String not an array and now I want to get the info from this string in arrays again