# How to process words one by one?

Tags: ios, swift

how can I pick words from a paragraph and process one by one. I want to switch places of letters except first and last letter. How can I?
Thanks

```
var fullInputArray = []
func convertToArray(){
    let fullInput = inputBox.text
    fullInputArray = fullInput.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    println("\(fullInputArray)") //prints [hello, world, this, is, an, app]
}


func processWords(){
    var processedArray: [String] = //something functional code like fullInputArray.mix
    println("\(processedArray)") //prints [hlleo, wlord, tihs, is, an, app]
}
```

Comment: Your question lacks a good title. Are looking for a way to exchange characters in a NSString object? Are looking for a way to split a NSString object by spaces?

Comment: Actually yes. I want to process words which seperated by space. ??? @ChristophH.

Comment: You will have to add some code of what you got done so far.

Comment: I've converted string to array acording to @ZaidPathan 's answer. You can see above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift: Split a String into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array)

Comment: It's not a duplicate of Swift: Split a String into an array. I asked how to process words. :) @milo526

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I put each word of a string into an array in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870385/how-can-i-put-each-word-of-a-string-into-an-array-in-swift)

Comment: It's not a duplicate man. I'm asking for change places of letters in a word. @LeoDabus

Comment: @Encul ok take a look at my answer

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm Sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import UIKit

extension Array {
    var shuffled: [T] {
        var result = self
        for index in 0..<result.count-1 {
            swap(&result[index], &result[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(result.count-index)))+index])
        }
        return result
    }
}

extension String {
    var wordList:[String] {
        return "".join(componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.punctuationCharacterSet())).componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    }
    var first: String {
        return String(self[startIndex])
    }
    var last: String {
        return String(self[endIndex.predecessor()])
    }
    var scrambleMiddle: String {
        if count(self) < 4 {
            return self
        }
        return first + String(Array(dropLast(dropFirst(self))).shuffled) + last
    }
}


let myWordListScrambled = "Hello Playground".wordList.map{$0.scrambleMiddle}

println(myWordListScrambled)   // "[Hlelo, Plnrgayoud]"
```

Note: Shuffle Extension variation from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24029847/2303865)

Comment: Should I add this code outside of ViewController class? Otherwise I'm getting an error(Decleration is only valid at file scope). Thus, I added it outside of ViewController class. But in that case, I cannot call UITextField instead of "Hello Playground"(myWordListScrambled). How can I fix it?

Comment: Yes all extensions must be placed out of your view controller.

Comment: Ok thanks. But how can I use inputBox instead of "Hello Playground"(myWordListScrambled)? I tried ViewController().inputBox but I got an error(UITextView does not have a member named 'wordList')

Comment: Hi, how can I use that code in swift 2.0? @LeoDabus

Answer (score 1):

You can split paragraph(String) into Array ,then access that Array indexes.

Try this answer to convert your String to Array :https://stackoverflow.com/a/26270721/3411787