# How to achieve like "LINE" input UITextView adding Tokens by Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Sorry, I'm beginner of Swift.
I have a question about inputView of Chat App.
How to add the tokens(tags) like "LINE" and separate normal string?
First, I use the UITextView and add the tagView on it, but I failed.
Does anyone know how to do like in the following image?

Or is this using the UIScrollView addSubView tagView and UITextView?
Have any sample to let me know how to achieve it?
Thanks.

[image: Image here.]

Comment: i hope it helps you check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28535519/9137841

Comment: Thanks your advice.