# Substring Swift iOS with an \n as limitation

Tags: ios, swift, substring, text-files

I'm quite unused to code with swift, it's very new for me (more used to code on Java or c#..)

I'm trying to do something very "easy" on other langages but I don't succeed to filter as I want a string, this is the code:

```
let id = self.Id.text
let pass = self.Pass.text
let documentDirectoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first! as! NSURL
let fileDestinationUrl = documentDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("file.txt")
let text = "Identifiant: " + id + "\n" + "Password: " + pass
text.writeToURL(fileDestinationUrl, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

This first portion of my code write on a text file datas, this is what the text file returns:

```
Identifiant: testId
Password: testPass
```

I'm tying to retrieve what `id` get and what `pass` get (in this case, testId and testPass..):

```
let startIndex = advance(text.startIndex, 14)
let endIndex = advance(startIndex, "to the \n character?")
//From the : to the \n, and then from the other : to the end, like shown after with Java code
let range = startIndex..<endIndex
var idFinal = text[range]
```

This is where I'm blocked. I have found the way to filter from a certain character (here the 14th), but I don't find the way to stop at a defined character with an unknown position. If anyone knows what am I supposed to do instead of `"to the \n character"`

With Java, I have done like this:

```
String ligne;
while((ligne = br1.readLine()) != null){
    if(ligne.startsWith("Identifiant: ")){
        System.out.println(ligne);
        id = ligne.substring(ligne.lastIndexOf(':')+2);
        }
    if(ligne.startsWith("Pass: ")){
        System.out.println(ligne);
        pass = ligne.substring(ligne.lastIndexOf(':')+2);
        }
    }
```

Is this possible with swift?
I hope I have been enough precise, I can add code or explanations if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array

Comment: Thanks for the link, i'll try it on my code

Comment: It's perfect, I have what I was looking for, I didn't knew split :)
Thank you. Can you post an answer with the link @ThomasKilian , that I could accept it

Comment: In that case your question is a duplicate :-)

Comment: Indeed X/ I searched with the bad keywords imo..