# Swift Convert comma separated string to NSMutableArray

Tags: swift

I have the following string

```
var points = "4,5"
```

I would like to convert to a mutable array so it becomes [4,5]
I tried the following but it did not work

```
   var points = "4,5" 
   var selectedArray : NSMutableArray = [points]
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Swift 2:**

Here you go:

```
var points = "4,5"
var pointsArr = split(points) {$0 == ","}
```

or

```
var pointsArr = points.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
```

Source: [Split a String into an array in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array)

**Swift 3:**

as [Genki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640588/Genki) mentioned:

```
var arr = points.components(separatedBy: ",")
```

Comment: This one liner saved me tons of time, thank you.

Comment: Swift 3: `var pointsArr = points.components(separatedBy: ",")`