# How to convert a string that looks like an array's values to an array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I've a string that looks like an array that shown below. How can I transform this string to an array like shown below? I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array) solution but I got an error from Xcode(Command failed due to signal segmentation fault 11) and I've thought this way too hard for compiler.

String:

```
var list = "<strong>UP</strong>, <strong>UP</strong>, <strong>DOWN</strong>, <strong>UP</strong>"
```

Target Array:

```
var array = [<strong>UP</strong>, <strong>UP</strong>, <strong>DOWN</strong>, <strong>UP</strong>]
```

And when I tried `let arr = list.characters.split {$0 == ","}` prints:

```
[Swift.String.CharacterView(_core: Swift._StringCore(_baseAddress: 0x0000000103152e40, _countAndFlags: 9223372036854775811, _owner: nil)), Swift.String.CharacterView(_core: Swift._StringCore(_baseAddress: 0x0000000103152e48, _countAndFlags: 9223372036854775812, _owner: nil)), Swift.String.CharacterView(_core: Swift._StringCore(_baseAddress: 0x0000000103152e52, _countAndFlags: 9223372036854775817, _owner: nil)), Swift.String.CharacterView(_core: Swift._StringCore(_baseAddress: 0x0000000103152e66, _countAndFlags: 9223372036854775816, _owner: nil)), Swift.String.CharacterView(_core: Swift._StringCore(_baseAddress: 0x0000000103152e78, _countAndFlags: 9223372036854775815, _owner: nil))]
```

With whitespace(`let arr = list.characters.split {$0 == ", "}`) gives compiler error:

- Command failed due to signal segmentation fault 11

Comment: Use the native `split` function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array

Comment: This does not work? `let arr = list.characters.split {$0 == ","}`

Comment: I've tried let arr = list.characters.split {$0 == ", "} edited...

Comment: Xcode gives error `... use split() function instead` @SalientGreen

Comment: What version of xcode are you using @twigofa?

Comment: Xcode 7.0 @SalientGreen

Comment: Straight 7.0? No beta version? @twigofa

Comment: try this: 
var array = split(list) {$0 == ",  "} @twigofa

Comment: solved, thanks @SalientGreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work:

```
var list = "<strong>UP</strong>, <strong>UP</strong>, <strong>DOWN</strong>, <strong>UP</strong>"

do {
    //Create a reggae and replace "," with any following spaces with just a comma
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: ", +", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)
    list = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(list, options: NSMatchingOptions.WithoutAnchoringBounds, range: NSMakeRange(0, list.characters.count), withTemplate: ",")
    var array = list.characters.split { $0 == ","}.map(String.init)
} catch {
    //Bad regex created
}
```

EDIT: Updated the example to remove componentsSeparatedByString for a native swift way.  The problem with your example is that the resulting array did not contain strings but what seems to be an internal class called CharacterView.  Mapping these back into Strings produces the desired output.

Output:

```
[
    "<strong>UP</strong>", 
    "<strong>UP</strong>", 
    "<strong>DOWN</strong>", 
    "<strong>UP</strong>"
]
```

Comment: A bit unnecessary since swift has a native function called `split`

Comment: True.  I've updated the example to do it natively in swift.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function that does that, componentsSeparatedByString

```
var array = list.componentsSeparatedByString(", ")
```