# Is there a way to remove everything after a certain character in a String?

Tags: string, swift

For example, I have a bunch of HTML entries ending in /"> and I want everything BEFORE this chunk. Is there a built-in method to get this done?

Maybe there is something like `replaceOcurrencesOfString()` that looks something like `removeRangeAfterOcurrenceOfString()` ?

**Example:**

I need this:

```
some-html-link-ending/">
```

To look like this:

```
some-html-link-ending
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array

Comment: You just want to make html to normal string or anything else??

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
mutating func replace(originalString:String, withString newString:String)
{
    let replacedString = self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(originalString, withString: newString, options: nil, range: nil)
    self = replacedString
}
```

Use:

```
name.replace("/">", withString: " ")
```