# How to use split and map method?

Tags: ios, swift

I saw a question: [Swift: Split a String into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array/26270721#26270721)

And there's some code I don't understand:

```
let fullName = "First Last"
let fullNameArr = split(fullName.characters){$0 == " "}.map{String($0)}

fullNameArr[0] // First
fullNameArr[1] // Last
```

How does `split()` and `map{}` work?

Comment: Both are documented in the Swift Standard Library Reference: [SequenceType Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/s:PSs12SequenceType). You can also option-click on the method name in Xcode for a quick help.

Comment: @MartinR the official document is inhumanly hard to understand for learners, I have no idea how it works under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a syntax that won't work in Xcode7. The correct syntax should be

```
let fullNameArr = fullName.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
```

Getting that out of the way let's break down that line into two pieces:

**split** takes

> A collection of Characters representing the String's extended
>   grapheme clusters

-- From Xcode docs

and a closure taking a character and returning Bool - true if the character can be considered as a separator.

if this syntax is confusing try reading that:

```
  fullNameArr = fullName.characters.split({
    character in
    return character == " "
  })
```

Now, **split** returns an array of SubSequence objects. You want to convert them back to string to be able to print them nicely. So one way of doing it would be creating a for loop iterating over all the results of split and converting them to string, then appending to a result array, or using **map** method that does the same.

If you look closely at the first line, you execute map on the array and pass a closure that does something with every element of the array and writes it back.

A simple example how that works

```
let exampleArray = [1, 2, 3]
print(exampleArray.map {$0 * 3})

// prints [3, 6, 9]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great! This is really easy to understand, thank you!