# Break string to newline when meeting a comma in SWIFT

Tags: string, swift, split, newline

I am receiving a string from a web service. I will set my label text to be the text of this string. However, the string contains a comma, and i want to separate the string to a new line, separated by a comma.

Example:

```
var exampleString = "street Number,  City"
```

needs to be

```
var wantedString = "street Number
                    City"
```

This is how i currently set my label text:

```
   self.AdresseLabel.text = self.SpillestedAdresse as String
```

Any ideas how to split the String?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26270721/1535436

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything fancy, just replace comma with new lines:

```
let wantedString = exampleString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(", ", withString: "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to replace a comma (followed by zero, one or more space characters) by a newline character, then a string replacement with a 
regular expression pattern is an option:

```
let exampleString = "street Number,  City"
let wantedString = exampleString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",\\s*",
    withString: "\n",
    options: .RegularExpressionSearch)

print(wantedString)
```

Output:

```
street Number
City
```