# Swift: String unable to read data

Tags: arrays, string, swift, split

After separating fields with

```
var fields = row.characters.split {$0 == "\t"}.map { String($0) }
```

the debugger shows "unable to read data" for one field.
What does it mean, except there is no data? I want to check it, but it is no empty string ("") and it's not nil.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Swift 2 in XCode 7? Might wanna give this a try:

```
var fields = row.characters.split {"\t"}.map(String.init)
```

Or maybe your problem is that `row` ends with a "\t" and the final string is not valid for String init. I would suggest split and then print your results as debug.

source: [Ethan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26270721/3462026)

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest version of XCode (7.2). It is not the final entry, it is in the middle. I found out that I could concatenate strings including this "unable" one and get a "-" character from this source. So I could check for "-" but this is not proper, bc. also "-" could be a valid value.