# Swift : How to convert String to [String]?

Tags: string, swift, character

I need to convert a classic `String` to a `[String]` (separating each character).

```
// let alphabet1 = ["a", "b",...
// let nombres1 = [1, 2,...
var name1 : String = "Hi"
let namet1 : [String] = name1.characters.map{String($0)}
func namepoints(name : [String], alphabet : [String], nombres : [Int]) -> Double {
    func nestedCountvalue(tableau : [String]) -> Int{
        var a : Int = 0
        for _ in tableau {
            a++
        }
        return a
    }
    var moy : Double = 0
    var p : Int = 0
    var i : Int = 0
    var o : Int = 0
    var pts : Int = 0
    p = nestedCountvalue(name)
    while i <= p{
        if name[i] == alphabet[o]{ // EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (Array index out of range)
            pts += nombres[o]
            o = 0
            i++
        } else {
            o++
        }
        if i == p {
            print("\(pts) points.")
            moy = Double(pts) / Double(p)
            print("\(moy) points en moyenne.")
            return moy
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for your answer, but is it actually converting a "Hello" into ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"] ? cause it isn't working with my code.

Comment: @LouisJouannet Isn't that what you wanted? (_separating each character_)

Comment: @LeoDabus Usually when we have these discussions it turns out, in the end, that I'm in the wrong, so I think you're probably most qualified to make that choice :D

Comment: I'd say this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array/26270721#26270721

Comment: I mean by separating : namet1[0] = "H" ; names[1] = "e" ...

Comment: the answer for your question is `let namet1 = Array(name1.characters)` if you want an array of characters and `let namet1 = name1.characters.map{String($0)}` if you want an array of strings

Comment: arrayLiteral ??? I never said to use that initializer

Comment: @LeoDabus both seems not working, it must be my code, thanks for the help anyway man

Comment: @LouisJouannet post your code and the error you got and which line it occurs

Comment: @LeoDabus here it is

Comment: I call function by : namepoints(namet1, alphabet : alphabet1, nombres : nombres1) @LeoDabus

Comment: You just need to check the characters count so you don't go out of bounds :)

Comment: JUST GOT IT, It was actually a problem of UpperCase that i didn't defined in the alphabet aha, thank you