# How do I get a string between slashes -Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string

I have string like so `"/blah//hahaha//lalala/"`

Which needs to be translated into an Array of strings so that if I printed the array it would look like this `print(arrayOfStrings) // prints ["blah","hahaha","lalala"]`

I am new to swift so forgive me if this question is foolish

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Split a String into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Given

```
let text = "/blah//hahaha//lalala/"
```

### you can

```
let chunks = String(text.characters.dropFirst().dropLast()).componentsSeparatedByString("//")
```

### and this is what you get

```
["blah", "hahaha", "lalala"]
```

Comment: let chunks = text.components(separatedBy: "/")

Answer (score 2):

There's also the URL solution

```
let string = "/blah//hahaha//lalala/"
let components = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: string).pathComponents!.dropFirst()
print(components)
```

Comment: Very smart, congrats. Can you describe why this code does also work with `//` instead of a single slash?

Comment: I cannot exactly describe why, but it seems that  `pathComponents` treats double slashes (even triple slashes) as one.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Thanks.