# Swift - Finding words in string and adding to array

Tags: ios, swift, string

I'm looking for a way to loop through a string and pull out words into an array where a certain prefix and suffix is contained.

For example, lets take the following string;

```
let str = "A Lorem @!ipsum!@ dolor sit amet, @!consectetur!@ adipiscing elit"
```

I need a way to search the text and output both the words ipsum and consectetur into an array to be used within another function later on.

Comment: i think answer for you question → http://stackoverflow.com/a/26270721/3485139

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
let input = "A Lorem @!ipsum!@ dolor sit amet, @!consectetur!@ adipiscing elit."
let words = input.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
let interesting = words.filter { $0.hasPrefix("@!") }
```

Comment: thanks for the input, this return the following

'use of unresolved indentifier 'CharacterSet'

Comment: That’s Swift 3. Update your Xcode or try to replace it with `NSCharacterSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression:

```
let text = "A Lorem @!ipsum!@ dolor sit amet, @!consectetur!@ adipiscing elit."
let pattern = "@!(\\w+)!@"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
let matches = regex.matches(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.characters.count))
let array = matches.map({(text as NSString).substring(with: $0.rangeAt(1))})
print(array)
```