# How to change syntax componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet to swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to change syntax "componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet" to swift 3. But I does not work. How could it adapt to swift 3? This is my code in ios 9. It showed "Value of type 'String' has no member of 'componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet'.

```
var delimiter = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: ",")
func parseHeaders(fromLines lines: [String]) -> [String] {
    return lines.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(self.delimiter)
}
```

Comment: One of the answers here has the Swift 3 way of doing it: [Swift: Split a String into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array)

Comment: @MrSaturn Thank you. I have just found the syntax accidentally. I can use 'lines.components(separatedBy: self.delimiter as CharacterSet)' to solve this.

Comment: All you needed to do was look at the documentation for `String`.

Comment: And since you are using Swift 3, don't use `NSCharacterSet`. Use `CharacterSet`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an answer already. Thanks.

```
func parseHeaders(fromLines lines: [String]) -> [String] {
    return lines.components(separatedBy: self.delimiter as CharacterSet)
}
```