# Extract information from a string

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I have strings in form of an URL. The strings looks like

```
http://www.somezwebsite.com/en/someString/xx-38944672
```

I am interested on the last part of the URL, the `/xx-38944672`. I need to extract the `xx` between the last `/` and the `-` which could be one or more characters. I also need to extract the number, `38944672` in this example. The number could also have a different length.

I think I could achieve this by determining the index of the last / the index of the last - and the index of the last character in the string, then proceed the sub-strings. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: split using '/' and then in the last element of the array (xx-38944672) split again and use '-' as the separator, your xx will be the first element of the array now, more info in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array

Comment: Anyway the regex is `/([^/]+?)-(\d+)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done this way:

```
let urlString = "http://www.somezwebsite.com/en/someString/xx-38944672"
        let str = urlString.components(separatedBy: "/").last
        let firstSring = str?.components(separatedBy: "-").first
        let secondString = str?.components(separatedBy: "-").last
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the one you needed:

```
/\w+(?=-)/g
```

[DEMO](http://regexr.com/3g19r)

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `URL` implies a part of the solution

The code takes the last path component of the URL and separates the value into two parts by the `-` character:

```
let url = URL(string:"http://www.somezwebsite.com/en/someString/xx-38944672")!
let components = url.lastPathComponent.components(separatedBy: "-")
if components.count == 2 {
    let firstPart = components[0]
    let secondPart = components[1]
    print(firstPart, secondPart)
}
```