# swift 2.0 split keyword from a string swift 3.1 migration

Tags: swift3

`split()` in swift 3 is deprecated. What will be alternate for below code:

```
var fullNameArr = split(str) {$0 == "@"}
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/q/25678373/2299040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let world = "Hello, world!".characters.suffix(6).dropLast()
String(world) // → "world"
```

Here split, which returns an array of subsequences, is also used for string processing. It’s defined like that:

```
extension Collection {
func split(maxSplits: Int = default,
    omittingEmptySubsequences: Bool = default,
    whereSeparator isSeparator: (Self.Iterator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows
    -> [AnySequence<Self.Iterator.Element>]
}
```

For **example**:

```
let commaSeparatedArray = "a,b,c".characters.split { $0 == "," }
commaSeparatedArray.map(String.init) // → ["a", "b", "c"]
```

For more detail in [split in swift 3](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/08/swift-3-strings/)