# Fastest way to parse text from an array

Tags: arrays, swift, parsing

I am trying to parse an array of items, each of which is structured like below:

```
[0x6100000b2480 - Message: Phlare, ID: 92329382, Sender: 2077303954, Timestamp: 1505263276721]
```

But I am just trying to get the value after "Sender:" so in this case "2077303954".  But I will be iterating through a list of these, parsing the value out of each array index.

Comment: What value do you have? Do you have a string? An array? Where did this come from? Provide more details and some relevant code.

Comment: Where are you getting this bizarrely formatted data from?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "`,`" only appears between values, separate them into pieces using `split`:

```
let arr = str.characters.split(separator: ",").map(String.init)
println(arr) // [0x6100000b2480 - Message: Phlare, ID: 92329382, Sender: 2077303954]
```

You can then split the strings in the resulting array again on "`:`" to get an array of alternating keys values.

Or perhaps the input was already an array?

Here's an example:

```
var resultingDictionary = [String:String]()
var stringArray = ["0x6100000b2480 - Message: Phlare", "ID: 92329382", "Sender: 2077303954", "Timestamp: 1505263276721:"]
for eachString in stringArray
{
    let arr = eachString.characters.split(separator: ":").map(String.init)
    resultingDictionary[arr[0]] = arr[1]
}

print("resulting dictionary is \(resultingDictionary)")
```

The same concept should work with NSString's `componentsSeparatedByString` [(now known as `components(separatedBy: ",")`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array).