# Creating Hashtags in swift

Tags: swift3, uitextfield

I am new to swift. I am trying to create a view where you can create hashtags. There is a `UITextfield` in which you type the word to be converted. On press of 'enter' or '#', it should automatically convert to hashtags and display in labels which are further stored in an array format.
I tried many tutorials but none of them seem to work.

Comment: Please add what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`UITextField`'s have a [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate) that is pretty handy.**

A really simple implementation would be to use the [textFieldShouldReturn](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619603-textfieldshouldreturn) delegate method, you can use this to detect when the return button is pressed.

Tell your view controller that it is going to adopt the protocol like this:

```
class ViewController:UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    ...
```

Then tell your textfield where to delegate it's events, if you are making the textfield inside the view controller then use `self` to reference the view controller like this:

```
let textField = UITextField()
textField.delegate = self // IMPORTANT
self.view.addSubView(textField)
```

Then inside your view controller implement the `textFieldShouldReturn` method like so:

```
class ViewController:UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    ...

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if let text = textField.text {
            let hashtag = "#\(text)"
            print("New hashtag is \(hashtag)")
        }
        return true // allows the default behaviour of return button, you can return false if you want the keyboard to remain on screen.
    }

}
```

This solution does not account for the user entering more than one hashtag, nor does it remove white space etc.. you may need to think about formatting/validating this string before it is useable.

You may also want to consider looking at other existing questions that cover things [like splitting strings and creating arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array).