# to cut a substring between two blank characters (spaces) of a string

Tags: macos, swift4, swift-playground

I want to cut several substrings out of a string, which are always between two whitespace, in order to use them further. but I get an extra sign (" ") at the end ...
What am I doing wrong? Who can help?

```
let text = "123045 7890 842 abcde fghij"
var index4Blank = text.index(of: " ")   // first 'blank'
index4Blank?.encodedOffset

// Find NEXT/last occurance of " "
if let rangeOfBlank = text.range(of: " ", options: .backwards) {
  // Get the characters between first 'blank' and next 'blank'
  let suffix = text[index4Blank!..<rangeOfBlank.upperBound] // "7890 "
  print(suffix)
}
```

what I want: "123045" and  "7890" and "842" and "abcde" and "fghij"
((Sorry for the question, but I'm really a beginner in Swift))

Answer (score 3):

```
let text = "123045 7890 842 abcde fghij"
var textArr = text.components(separatedBy: " ") // For swift 3+
var textArr = text.split(separator: " ") // For swift 4
print(textArr)
```

You can get substrings using this code in array called "textArr".

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Thank you - but then I get the message: Use of unresolved identifier 'split'. What am I missing there?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question literally:

- `index(of:` – as the name implies – returns the index of the first character of the found string, in your case the space character after `123045`
- `range(of: ... ).upperBound` returns the index of the character **after** the found string so the last space character is included.

To remove the leading and trailing whitespace with your code you have to use `lowerBound` for the upper bound and `range(of:` calling `upperBound` for the lower bound.

```
let text = "123045 7890 842 abcde fghij"
if let index4Blank = text.range(of: " "),

    // Find NEXT/last occurance of " "
    let rangeOfBlank = text.range(of: " ", options: .backwards) {
    // Get the characters between first 'blank' and next 'blank'
    let suffix = text[index4Blank.upperBound..<rangeOfBlank.lowerBound] // "7890 "
    print(suffix)
}
```

However to split a string into parts by a given separator there are better ways like in the other answer or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array)