# Create Modal class from String in Swift 4.2

Tags: arrays, swift, class

I have two string `var strDate = "2019-10-14, 2019-07-30"` and `var strID = "162670, 127097"`, i wan to create `class` modal from above two string and append to ModalData like :

```
class ModalData{
    var id:String
    var booking_date:String

    init(id:String,booking_date:String) {

        self.id = id
        self.booking_date = booking_date
    }
}
```

and show modal to class to `UITableView` in Swift.

Comment: what's issue with given model example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a String into an array in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/split-a-string-into-an-array-in-swift)

Comment: Unrelated but why are the properties optional? They are clearly initialized with non-optional values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
class ModalData
{
    var id:           String
    var booking_date: String

    init(id: String, booking_date: String)
    {
        self.id           = id
        self.booking_date = booking_date
    }
}

var strDate = "2019-10-14, 2019-07-30"
var strID   = "162670, 127097"

let dateArray = strDate.split(",").map { $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) }
let idArray   = strID.split(",").map { $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) }

var modalDataArray = [ModalData]()
for i in 0..<max(dateArray.count, idArray.count)
{
    modalDataArray.append(ModalData(id: idArray[i], booking_date: dateArray[i]))
    print(modalDataArray.last!)
}
```

What this does is:

- Turn the string of dates into an array of dates (`dateArray`).
- Turn the string of ids into an array of ids (`idArray`).

(Both splitting by `,` and removing whiteSpaces around the string)

Then check the max amount in both arrays, just to be safe.
Using this, we can loop through the array and create `ModalData` objects.

Comment: This can probably be optimized (written in nicer/shorter way). But it does the job.

Comment: What do you mean with 'print together'? Also, `print(modalDataArray)` definitely won't print `[CheckTableViewBack.OPDModalPrevious,...]`.

Comment: what version of swift are you using?

Comment: If you're using my code, you can just do `print(modalDataArray)`. You're probably just doing something else, since `[CheckTableViewBack.OPDModalPrevious,...]` is printed.

Comment: You can also print it inside the `for`-loop. I added this to the code. Or you can do `modalDataArray.forEach { print("id: \($0.id), booking_date: \($0.booking_date)") }`.

Comment: thanks its working bro and also i m giving upvote to you if any question or issue i will mention here@JeroenJK

Comment: Good, no problem :-) And yes, let me know any problem you have!